# Norm of linear transformation: why restrict ourselves to $\|x\|\leq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

If $f$ is linear transformation from a normed linear space $X$ into a normed linear space $Y$, and define its norm by

$$\|f\|=\sup\{\|f(x)\|: x\in X, \ \|x\|\leq 1\}$$

My question is: **why restrict ourselves to vectors $x$ with $||x||\leq 1$?**

Answer (score 3):

It is always defined as $||f||=sup\{\frac{||f(x)||}{||x||},x\in X$, x is non-zero$\}$, and this can be transformed to the form in your question.

Comment: Slight correction: $\|f(x)\|$ instead of $\|f\|$ in your supremum.

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to. For linear functionals you can show that the above definition is equivalent to 
$$
\|f\|=\sup_{x\not=0}{\|f(x)\|_Y\over \|x\|_X},
$$
(where subscripts denote the norm from the appropriate space) as follows (using the [absolute homogeneity property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) of norms and basic linearity for $f$):
\begin{align}
{\|f(x)\|_Y\over \|x\|_X}=\left\|{f(x)\over \|x\|_X}\right\|_Y=\left\|f\left({x\over \|x\|_X}\right)\right\|_Y&=\|f(t)\|_Y\text{ where $t$ is unit vector in $X$}
\end{align}
so
$$
\sup_{x\not=0}{\|f(x)\|_Y\over \|x\|_X}=\sup_{\|t\|_X=1}\|f(t)\|_Y.$$